# Setting area for draggable item (without using jQuery draggable)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Another draggable div question but without using jQuery draggable UI this time. Reason why I don't want to use jQuery is that it's quite heavy for mobile devices. There's ~1 sec loading delay which I don't want. Goal is to make this work on iPhones and iPads. I have been using [this](http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/) example but I would like to set an area for the draggable item. The item shouldn't be able to go outside the area. Is there an easy way to set area which div can't be dragged over? You can use the [original](http://www.midemos.com/demos/iphone/touch/) example or my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#touchme {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: lightgreen;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.touch.compact.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentRotation=null;

function checkOrientAndLocation(){
    if(currentRotation != window.orientation){
        setOrientation();
    }
}

function setOrientation(){
    switch(window.orientation){
        case 0:
            orient = 'portrait';
            break;
        case 90:
            orient = 'landscape';
            break;
        case -90:
            orient = 'landscape';
            break;
    }
    currentRotation = window.orientation;
    document.body.setAttribute("orient",orient);
    setTimeout(scrollTo,0,0,1);
}

$().ready(function(){
    setInterval(checkOrientAndLocation,1000);
    $('#touchme').touch({
        animate: false,
        sticky: false,
        dragx: false,
        dragy: true,
        rotate: false,
        resort: false,
        scale: false
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="touchme">Drag me!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or another solution I accept is that how can I reduce the size of 3 different libraries which I need to use to achieve the same. Here are the libraries I have used: jquery-1.6.2.min.js (94 kb), jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min (37 kb) and [jquery.ui.touch](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) (8 kb).